# Chatset in debug tab of Node-Red

Tags: serial-port, node-red

Hi i need know if is possible change the charset of the: "Debug" tab on Node-Red.
Im trying get incoming serial data and show in "Debug" tab, but the input data has rare characters and is not displayed correctly.
Input String example:

> "...H.Y.ÝAW.J...~.›..Lé.$...H.Y.ÛGW."

I can send the message to console using:

> console.log(msg.payload)

and view this characters, but cannot in debug tab.

Thank's.

Comment: What does it say across the top of the entry in the debug window?

Comment: Appear a question simbol: "?".

Comment: The debug tab says what type of object the msg.payload is it's trying to display, I was wondering if it thinks it's a buffer or string

Comment: When I set de Serial In node to get ASCII String I see questions simbols, but if I set it to buffer, I can see an Array.